# Who would win? Texas Holdem

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Card Scenario
in Texas Holdem
Player 1 has... Q♥ and 4♠
Player 2 has... J♥ and 5♣
The community cards are ♠A, Q, 8, 7, 3

(I hope I explained it right) Can someone help?

Answer (score -2):

In this case:

- Player 1 has the higher hand with ♠AQ874 using the 4♠
  in her hand
- player 2 has ♠AQ873

Comment: Not sure why the 2 downvotes without comments, this answer appears correct.